# Replace Double quote with double double quote with awk

Tags: linux, bash, awk, substring, gsub

I am  writing a script with awk to replace all double quote with double double quote for all files in folder.

I found this in stackoverflow but i get other result

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"} {for (i=0;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/"/, "&&",$i)} 1 $f3 > $f2
```

the output for this example example :

```
01##"hello world"98##
```

is

```
01##""""hello world""""98##
```

And I would like to get

```
01##""hello world""98##
```

Comment: How does your input file look like? `$f3` contents?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply
01##"hello world"98##

Comment: if you are fine with `sed` `sed 's/"/&&/g' inputfile`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To replace all double quotes with two double quotes, use sed:

```
sed 's/"/""/g' file
```

No need for anything fancier than that.

To do this on all files in a directory, use the in-place option if your version of sed supports it:

```
sed -i.bak 's/"/""/g' *
```

This creates backups of each file with the suffix `.bak`.

If you can't use `-i`, then use a loop with a temporary file:

```
for i in *; do 
    sed 's/"/""/g' "$i" > tmp && mv tmp "$i"
done
```

Or there's always good old `ed`:

```
for i in *; do
    ed -s "$i" <<< $',s/"/""/g\nw'
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Just lose the loop etc:

```
$ echo '01##"hello world"98##' | awk '{gsub(/"/,"&&")}1'
01##""hello world""98##
```

Read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 0):

Change the loop to

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="#"} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) gsub(/"/, "&&",$i)} 1' $f3 > $f2
```

When the loop starts with 0, it first replaces `"` with `""` for `$0` (entire line in this context) and then again for per-field.

But actually, you could just make it compact with:

```
awk '{gsub(/"/,"\"\"");}1' $f3 > $f2
```

Or

```
sed 's/"/""/g' $f3 > $f2
```

Comment: @EdMorton: 
Right... In OP's code, it started at 0. So, it replaced twice as I mentioned...

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '01##"hello world"98##' |
```

> ```
> {m,g,n}awk NF=NF FS='"' OFS='""'
> ```

```
01##""hello world""98##
```